# How to decide what entities to store in a database

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-web-api2

I was following along the following tutorial by Microsoft on ASP.net and WebApi:

[Working With Data Tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-2)

Over in this example, two separate models were created: one for Authors and one for Books. When a booked is stored in a database, an author id is stored along with it as a navigation property.

My question is this: Why do we need a separate table for the authors. Why not store the author name directly inside the Books table? If you are interested to find out the unique authors, we can always do a query directly from the Books table.

I want to extend this question to a more general approach on deciding what to store in a separate table when dealing with data like this.

Thank you. Sorry if it is a silly question.

Comment: Normalization: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets consider what problems it solves by considering scenarios -

1. Authors can be in thousands while book in millions. So to find unique authors are we going to scan million records? - No.
2. Separation of concern - Used as strategy. When I only required authors information,  i would be least interested in books first. By using stategy I can formulate different combinations to serve requests with required subsets.
3. Book can have multiple authors - Isn't it? So, if we have single table then what should be strategy for store and would we find difficulty in forming subsets?
   In this scenario it is difficult to make parent child relation. Book can have author and Author can have books :-). So, in this case two separate entities with lookup in place will definatly help.

Answer (score 0):

lets say, in future you want to get the autor bank acount or to make a list of stores for that the author sells books to etc., we don't want to hold in every table all of his\her details (it's not only his \ her name, becuase it means we need to maintain all there tables and it makes the table very heavy. For that purpose we create a table with an identifier of the author and his\her details.

Good Day :)